# Local node_modules in different location

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I'm working on an Angular project on a distante machine via a VM and I'm oblige to delete the node_modules folder before closing my session. If not, loading my profile will crash because of the node_modules size (400Mb).

Is there any way to save node_modules in another location and use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no way to do this. However, even if there was I believe it would be the wrong solution.

I’ve have plenty of experience of working remotely on vms and there is no reason why this 400mb folder should crash your system.

Get the system administrator to fix this issue instead